# How many permutations (bijections) are there on the set B = {0,1}^(8) of bytes? How can there be permutations if there is no function?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

I know that B would be the set {00000000, 00000001, ..., 11111111}, and there are 256 elements on this set. I don't know how there can be a bijection on the set, though...I thought that you needed a function in order to have a bijection, and my teacher didn't give us a function. I was thinking that I could use the identity function and say that there would be 256 permutations since there are 256 elements, but I don't know if this would be right... I'm really confused as to how there can be permutations on a set when there is no function.

Comment: Between any two sets there exists a function (if you call $\emptyset$ a function, at least; otherwise, require they be non-empty). For example, here, the constant function $x\mapsto (00000000)$. There are $256^{256}-1$ other functions, though, of which some are bijective.

Comment: So should I be comparing the set B to the empty set? How would that work? Because this problem doesn't give any other sets.

Comment: No, permutations are bijections $B\to B$. You just need to find out how many such bijections exist. If you think you've got a formula that works, try to prove it by induction on $|B|$, the number of elements in $B$.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it helps to know that a permutation is a bijection from a set to itself. So, the question is asking how many functions are there from $B$ to $B$ that meet the requirements of a bijection.

Try thinking about a smaller space that is easier to picture or write out. For example, suppose we are in $\{0, 1\}^2 = \{00, 01, 10, 11\}$. A bijection is just a mapping between sets, with a few extra rules. Using what you know about bijections, what does such a mapping look like in this case?

The identity function is one example to consider. Here's another:

\begin{align*}
 00 & \mapsto 01 \\
 01 & \mapsto 11 \\
 10 & \mapsto 00 \\
 11 & \mapsto 10 \\
\end{align*}

When coming up with new bijections, notice that there are four ways to pick what $00$ maps to, then three remaining ways to pick what $01$ maps to, and so on. Given this, how many such bijections can there be? Now extend this to the case of $\{0, 1\}^8$, or even $\{0, 1\}^n$. In order to show that the rule holds for any $n$, you can use mathematical induction.

Comment: Oh! So should it be the factorial of however many elements are in the set? So instead of 256 permutations, there would be 256! ?

Comment: @user108471 Yes. On a set of $n$ elements there are $n!$ permutations.